# Excel. IDs and sub IDs. Copy / potential substitution formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying take a list of IDs which are in column C. To the right are Sub_Ids which are broken into individual columns. Currently, I am trying to write a formula which will tell excel that when there is a ID with 2 Sub_IDs in columns to the right. take the second Sub-ID, insert new row. copy to the row below. and copy the associated ID with it.

really struggling with this and the long work around formulas and several sheets has become heavily time consuming. Does anyone have an idea of how to accomplish this?

[image]

NA

Comment: You can't insert a new row with formulas. That'll require scripting, e.g. using VBA.

Comment: how extensive would a vba be to do this?

Comment: Honestly I think you're just looking for Power Query - Unpivot here.

Comment: thank you that actually worked. you just saved me days of work